# Preserve exit code when using '$PROMPT_COMMAND'

Tags: bash, shell, exit-code

I have the following code ([simplified for clarity](https://gist.github.com/IQAndreas/5d22728244b6cbcf59b4)) which is called by `$PROMPT_COMMAND` after every command:

```
function previous_command_status() 
{
    exit_code=$?;
    if [ $exit_code -eq 0 ]; then
        echo "Command successful"
    else
        echo "Command failed with exit code $exit_code"
    fi
}
```

The problem is, it seems the `[ $exit_code -eq 0 ]` part is changing the exit code, so I am unable to use or store the exit code after the command has finished running. For example:

```
$ ./failing_script.sh
Command failed with exit code 255
$ echo $?;
1   # this is the exit code of the 'if' statement, not of 'bad'
```

I cannot "pass the value along", because if I add the line `exit $exit_code` inside the function, the terminal window closes *immediately*.

Is there any way for me to "preserve" the exit code of the previous command, or run a set of commands in such a way that they won't modify the exit value?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't preserve it. Even if you use `case` statements `echo` would still alter it. However you can put it back with `return`:

```
exit_code=$?;
if [ $exit_code -eq 0 ]; then
    echo "Command successful"
else
    echo "Command failed with exit code $exit_code"
fi
return "$exit_code"
```

You can use another global variable to store the code however.

Comment: I'm used to Java and ECMA-based languages; looks like I really need to read up on how `return` is used in Bash.

Comment: Why did you put quotes around `$exit_code`, isn't it always going to be an integer value (without spaces)?

Comment: @IQAndreas Just a good practice even if IFS never gets a numerical value.